# Yesod - Esqueleto vs Views

Tags: sql, haskell, view, yesod

I have noticed that `Esqueleto` is quite similar to SQL, and in my opnion, much more complex than simple `Persistent` entities. Wouldn't it be simpler (and maybe more efficient) if we just used views? And, how can I tell Yesod to not try to migrate those entities which are actually just simple view?

Comment: I've been thinking, and realised that `Views` represents an extra layer of complexity on the database side, so `Esqueleto` is better considering it because I will manage this complexity in Haskell and not on the database...

Comment: also persistent supports non-relational data-*dumps* too - and not all of those really use the concept of a *view*